# Grafana edit provisioned contact points

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I want to provision contact-points to my Grafana in Kubernetes.
My config:

```
  contact_points.yaml: |
    apiVersion: 1
    contactPoints:
      - orgId: 1
        name: telegram-alerts
        receivers:
          - uid: telegram_receiver_1
            type: telegram
            disableResolveMessage: false
            settings:
              chatid: <CHAT_ID>
              bottoken: <TOKEN>
              message: |
                {{"{{"}} template "telegram.message" . {{"}}"}}
```

After import I see this point in Grafana UI with status "Provisioned"
[image]
But there is not edit button. How can I edit contact point in Grafana UI? I tried to add field "editable: true" but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not able to edit these within Grafana, see the below note from [this doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/view-provisioned-resources/).

> You cannot edit provisioned resources from files in Grafana. You can only change the resource properties by changing the provisioning file and restarting Grafana or carrying out a hot reload. This prevents changes being made to the resource that would be overwritten if a file is provisioned again or a hot reload is carried out.

If that is important to you, you could instead look to provision them using the HTTP API or using Terraform, both of these options support editing as detailed in the same doc.